# Qt - How to create a Menu like this using Qt

Tags: qt, menu

hello im new i Qt and i want to create a vertical menu like in the picture , can any body help  me ?

[image]

Comment: Please, see how to ask questions - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Post some code, that you already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use `QSystemTrayIcon` and `QMenu`.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QSystemTrayIcon.html (Qt Widget applications)

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qplatformsystemtrayicon.html (Qt QML applications?)

A good example to get you started on using system tray icons in Qt:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/desktop-systray.html (doesn't look like the Qt 5 example of the system tray icon is posted online yet)

Basically, you use the system tray icon class to create the icon and is a button that can be activated.  The activated button will pop out a qmenu in your case that you would want to populate.

The easiest styling of the QMenu is through the `QStyleSheets`.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qmenu

```
QMenu {
    background-color: #ABABAB; /* sets background of the menu */
    border: 1px solid black;
}

QMenu::item {
    /* sets background of menu item. set this to something non-transparent
        if you want menu color and menu item color to be different */
    background-color: transparent;
}

QMenu::item:selected { /* when user selects item using mouse or keyboard */
    background-color: #654321;
}
```

And here is an excellent example to get you started with `QMenu` and context menu popups.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-menus-example.html

Hope that helps.